# Delete random rows in table but left fixed amount of entries

Tags: sql, mariadb, mariadb-10.6

I have a table with unknow number of rows in it. I need to remove all the rows, except a fixed number of records.

Example: Table 1 has 439 rows. I need to keep 200 rows randomly and delete others.

The "logic way" is:

````
DELETE FROM table_1 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table_1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 200)```
````

But mariaDB says

> You cannot use LIMIT in subquery ...

How I can do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION();` return?

Comment: 10.6.7-MariaDB-1:10.6.7+maria~buster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution tested on MariaDB 10.6:

```
delete t1 from table_1 as t1
left join (select id from table_1 order by rand() limit 200) as t2
using (id)
where t2.id is null;
```

Demo:
https://dbfiddle.uk/zygpZ0u0